# how have a smooth lasso tool before select an area

Tags: adobe-photoshop

i wish to give smooth to lasso tool as we can set feather for that with 
feather box.

[image]

as you know we can set feather and smooth after selecting an area but i want to know is there any way to set smooth for lasso tool before of select an area?